# Two Moderators Needed - Apply WIthin

Tags: discussion, moderation

While they'll always be a guiding force for this site, [Andrew](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users/2/andrew-spitz) and [Iain](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users/80/iain-mcgregor) don't have as much time as they used to when it comes to daily moderation of the site. Don't worry - they're not going anywhere, but they would *much* rather that their slots be used by folks that have more time to actively work on the problems and challenges that Sound Design faces.

I'm looking for two users that:

- Have a reasonably thorough knowledge of Sound Design, and audio production in general
- Are patient, fair and able to help lead this community
- Have a few hours per week *on average* they can allot for moderating the site
- Have read and understand our [theory of moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), guiding principles that have proven to be the key to success for community self-moderation on our sites

What will you do, exactly? The job is a *tad* more involved here, as we face some very unique challenges, but the tasks at hand are just *waiting* for folks with the right kind of creativity to meet them. You'll be:

- Working with the rest of the moderation team and myself to help solidify the scope and identity of the site
- Help re-organize tags so that folks following (or ignoring) them can enjoy a more interesting mix of questions
- Step in and take action where the community *can't*, and help resolve topic and content disputes

I've already made it sound more complicated than it actually is - if you care about the site and have been actively working to improve and curate it, you'll be able to just keep doing what you're doing - it'll just be easier with a diamond next to your name.

If you're interested, you can reply in an answer to this question, or email me directly at `tpost@[nospam]stackoverflow.com`, of course you'll need to remove my very primitive anti-lunch meat measures.

I'd like to get folks appointed over the next two weeks, if you even *think* you might be interested in the job - please reach out to me to talk about it.

Good luck!

Comment: And I'll also add that Tim isn't joking when he said he made it sound more complicated than it is.  There is some initial clean up efforts needed, but the permission fix should help the community clean itself up and moderating really isn't hard or a big time commitment at all.  (I'm a moderator on video production.)  If you really know the community and want to be able to help it grow, being a moderator is a great way to help it do that.

Comment: New moderators have been appointed :)

Answer (score 7):

i nominate

[arnoud-traa](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1216/arnoud-traa)

he seems to have an attitude toward caring.

b

Comment: Thanks Brad (and 7 others). I do care, like you, but I'm very busy and feel that we would need to change some things here that I would not be able to change. A stricter 'door policy' would be a start.. And someone should finally change the landing page, because this is not helping :)

Comment: @ArnoudTraa - moderation really isn't a big time commitment (I don't spend substantially more time on video production as a mod than I did before I was a mod) and I do think it would be helpful having you on board as a moderator.  I notice you are around here and commenting a fair bit, but could take action more quickly to clean up the rampantly bad questions that fit no forms of the site that are even being discussed or desired by anyone.

Comment: Allright allright I'll do it.. Let me contact Tim Post

Answer (score 3):

I'll throw my name in to the hat.  I'm unfortunately not from the SSD side of things originally, but I think I've come to understand their concerns fairly well.  I think I personally probably have a slightly broader view of what could be on-topic than some parts of the community, but I also see a lot of the same issues too.  As someone who tends to be one of the more forgiving members of the community when it comes to what is on or off-topic, I would be more comfortable VTCing and removing questions that are clearly far from what the community wants and helping keep it more clear what the site is about for someone just looking at the main page.

I think the main problem the site has right now is that new users don't understand what is and isn't a fit and things are enough of a mess that they can't figure it out easily.  My primary concern would be addressing that issue.  After that is dealt with, it would fall more in to the more traditional moderator role of stepping in whenever the community isn't able to act and helping empower the community to govern itself.